# Display some content while playing audio in MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, audio, mediaelement

I am using `<MediaElement/>` for preview media content of my media elements collection. They are pictures, videos and audios.

While playing audio I see nothing in the `<MediaElement/>` frame but I hear the audio.

What should I do for tuning the `<MediaElement/>` in purpose to see a related content of selected audio or at least to see a thumbnail of the audio file?

Answer (score 0):

The MediaElement frame will not show anything during audio playback.

However, you could show the album art of an .mp3 file by using [TagLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/taglib/)

Install TagLib and add the corresponding namespaces. Then, write your program so that when an audio file is being played, an image showing the cover art is displayed using the following code.

I'd also recommend running this inside try-catch incase the audio file has no cover art.

```
TagLib.File f = new TagLib.Mpeg.AudioFile(*yourfile*);

TagLib.IPicture pic = f.Tag.Pictures[0];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(pic.Data.Data);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
bitmap.EndInit();

System.Windows.Controls.Image CoverArt = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
CoverArt.Source = bitmap;
```